# VSCODE gives error, when trying to debug javascript: "vscode listen eacces: permission denied 127.0.0.1:53942"

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-code

Environment is win 10. Code lines, which i try to debug:

```
let x='xxx';
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 11):

I've ran into this error a few times in VSCode while working on some NodeJS apps and it is an easy fix.

```
net stop winnat
net start winnat
```

You don't even have to restart VSCode, just restart your debugger and you should be good. I don't know why Windows 10 NAT gets all buggy but this will give it a kick.

Answer (score 2):

First thing to do is to check if the port is already in use.

```
netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp
```

Maybe try running the server on a different port or rebooting Windows to see if it frees up the port if nothing else is using it.